# Set cookie if a variable is present on any action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, arguments

I've got a couple of variables that I'd like to universally be watched for in the url.  If they are set in the url I'd like to set a cookie to store this information.

For example...

`http://www.website.com/?SomeVariable=something`

and

`http://www.website.com/SomeController/SomeAction?SomeVariable=something`

In both cases I'd like `SomeVariable` to be responded to (and I want this on ANY Controller/Action throughout the website.

I have the cookie part of it worked out and functioning on the home page, but I'm wanting to drop people on some url's besides the homepage now and would prefer to not have to redo the logic any time that this changes.

Can this be done?  Where should I put the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I ended up figuring out what I needed to do based on information from both Matt Tew and user850010.

Custom Action Filter:

```
public class CheckForAd : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuted( ActionExecutedContext filterContext ) {
        var data = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString["AdName"];

        if( data != null ) {
            HttpCookie aCookie = new HttpCookie( "Url-Referrer" );
            aCookie.Value = data;
            aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays( 2 );
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add( aCookie );
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted( filterContext );
    }
}
```

Once I had my custom action filter I was able to go to the `Global.asax`

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    ...
    filters.Add( new CheckForAd() );
}
```

This allows me to set the cookie from ANY Action/Controller without requiring me to decorate an action/controller.  This also doesn't require my controllers to derive from anything besides the standard `Controller` (I didn't want to forget this and then not have a cookie set when it needed to be).

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom action filter, and then look for the request variables and set the cookies inside it.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Based on this I'll need to decorate EVERY action/controller that I want to look for this (unless I can register it someplace that will make it apply to everything).  This is what I'm wanting to get away from.  I don't want to have to make sure that my controllers/actions are decorated.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom controller that will read the variable, something like

```
public class BaseController:Controller
{
    protected override void ExecuteCore()
    {

      var somevar = HttpContext.Request.QueryString["SomveVariable"];
      .
      .
      .
      base.ExecuteCore();
    }
}
```

Then derive all controllers from this custom controller.